# spectral decomposition of $H_u$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $V$ a complex vector space with dimension n and inner product ,$u \in V $ unit vector. 
Let $ H_u: V \rightarrow V$  defined by $ H_u(v) = v - 2 <v,u>u$ $\forall v \in V$.
Then:

a)$H_u(u) = -u$

b)$H_u(v) = v$ iff $v$ is orthogonal to $u$

c) Find the characteristic polynomial  of $H_u$

d) Find the spectral decomposition of $H_u$

I could prove a) and b) but how can i solve c) and d) some help please. I don't understand the concept of spectral decomposition some clarity please?

Comment: well i don't understand the concept of spectral descomsition

Comment: That's the sort of information that would have been good to include in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we can make an orthonormal basis of *eigenvectors* of $H_u$, by extending $u$ by an arbitrary orthonormal basis $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}$ of the $n-1$ dimensional subspace $u^\perp$.

Can you write up the matrix of $H_u$ in this basis $(u,v_1,\dots,v_{n-1})$?

The characteristic polynomial of a linear transformation that has a basis of eigenvectors, is $\prod_{i=1}^n(x-\lambda_i)$ where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues.

Now $u$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$ (as $H_u(u)=(-1)\cdot u$), and each $v_j$ has eigenvalue $1$.